# How to setup SYSLOG in Centos for more than 8 devices?

Tags: centos, syslog

I currently have syslog configuration files using local0 to local7 setup in such a way, that a particular device is assign to an specific local facility pointing to separate directories and files for the device, for example:

*Entries related to the SYSLOG SERVER

*DEVICE1

local1.=emerg   /location/device1/00-emerg

local1.=alert   /location/device1/01-alert

local1.=crit    /location/device1/02-crit

*DEVICE2

local2.=emerg   /location/device2/00-emerg

local2.=alert   /miramar/device2/01-alert

local2.=crit    /miramar/device2/02-crit

The problem is that this way only 8 devices can be specified
How can I setup syslog to work with more than 8 devices?

Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of (or in addition to) using syslog facilities, consider replacing the stock syslogd with [syslog-ng](http://www.balabit.com/products/syslog_ng/). Among other things, it allows you to filter remote log messages based on the address of the host that sent them. We have a simple setup on our syslog server that does this:

> `source remote_log { udp(ip(x.x.x.x) port(514)); };`
>   `destination remote { file("/var/log/remote/$HOST.log"); };`
>   `log { source(remote_log); destination(remote); };`

This causes syslog message for each host to end up in `/var/log/remote` in a file named after the hosts' IP addresses. syslog-ng lets you get a lot fancier than that if you want to (e.g. filtering individual messages based on regular expression matches), but this covers what you were asking about.

There are syslog-ng packages in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) for [CentOS 4](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/4/i386/repoview/syslog-ng.html) and [CentOS 5](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/repoview/syslog-ng.html)

Comment: +1 for including helpful configuration details.

Answer (score 2):

You could log multiple servers to the same local#, but if you want separate files you should look at something like [syslog-ng](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/).